# Reverse search query - search from high to low

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, where-clause, sql-limit

I want to fetch messages with given parameters:

```
select * 
  from chat.messages 
 where senderId = 1 
   and receiverId = 0 
    or senderId = 0 
   and receiverId = 1 
 order 
    by id ASC 
 LIMIT 0,10
```

Instead of start search from the lowest id, I want to reverse it and start with the highest id in order to get the most recent ones.

Comment: The astute use of parentheses is required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just want a descending sort?

```
select * 
from chat.messages 
where (senderid = 1 and receiverid = 0) 
   or (senderid = 0 and receiverid = 1) 
order by id desc limit 0,10
```

Note that I also fixed a logical flaw issue in your `where` clause: `and` has higher precedence than `or`, so the `or` condition need to be surrounded with parentheses. Otherwise your `where` clause is equivalent to:

```
where senderid = 1 and (receiverid = 0 or senderid = 0) and receiverid = 1
```

... which obviously is not what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use order by DESC

```
select * from chat.messages where senderId = 1 and receiverId = 0 or senderId = 0 and receiverId = 1 order by id DESC LIMIT 0,10
```